# Entity Framework and ObjectContext references

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

I am playing around with Entity Framework to see how it can be used in a new project I am working on. I put my edmx file in a class library so the Entities (and database access) can be used in multiple places. Currently I have a web project and a console project both referencing the class library.

One of my Entities has a Partial class defined with a static method. The purpose of the method is to accept some parameters and create one or more instances of the specific class. My first version of the method created an ObjectContext instance, created the Entity class (or classes), and returned the Entities to the calling method. The calling method then updated some properties and tried to save the Entities using a new ObjectContext instance. Obviously this did not work because the Entities were bound (correct term ??) to the Context created within the static method.

After some research, I modified the static method to also accept an ObjectContext reference to ensure that all the Entities where created and then later on manipulated and saved using the same Context. This works fine but the design just feels wrong.

Assuming that my one static method may grow into many more, or that my app (especially the web app) would probably benefit from additional layers (DAL or even a Service Layer), does it make sense for all these classes to require an ObjectContext parameter?

I have read on many postings that creating an ObjectContext via a Singleton pattern is a bad idea because "many clients would use the same object". My problem with that is I do not see how that is possible. In a local console app there is only a single user running the app. In a web app there would only be a single user on each request. Where is the user sharing problem? Not a single article/posting mentioned it...but where they referring to a Singleton pattern storing the object instance in the Application context?

I have also seen postings focused on web usage and storing the object instance in the users Session object via the HttpContext object. This makes sense but does not seem to address non-web usage.

I think that whatever solution is appropriate (static methodm, Factory object, etc.) would most likely be implemented in my class library so obviously it needs to support both web and non-web solutions. Maybe check for HttpContext to determine what environment it is running in.

I was hoping http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management would be informative but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the post and the example code seems like overkill for instantiating and sharing a simple object. (Although I am sure I am just not getting it...)

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: (partly) duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927779/managing-entity-framework-objectcontext-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that “many clients would use the same object.” The issue is that the ObjectContext is intended to be a single unit of work. If you use it for many different units of work, you will find that there are a number of problems.

- Memory usage will grow and grow.
- Your application will become slower as object fixup has to do increasing amounts of work.
- Multithreading won't work

The solution is to use the ObjectContext in the manner it is intended, namely, as a single unit of work.